# Trouble connecting to https secure web service using Adobe Livecycle Designer

Tags: web-services, forms, https, adobe, livecycle-designer

I am attempting to use Adobe Livecycle Designer ES2 to create a data connection in an XFA Form to a secure (https) web service and I'm having some difficulty.

I'm new to Livecycle and have tried searching online for an answer, but the Adobe help isn't very clear and the only tutorials online that I can find are ones that connect to non-https services.

The WSDL I'm trying to connect to is: https://uk.ws.ondemand.qas.com/ProOnDemand/V3/ProOnDemandService.asmx?WSDL

My questions are: 
Q1. Does Adobe Livecycle support https web service connections? The following link suggests that this isn't possible: http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=yOOcM3Bn4BAC&pg=PA179&lpg=PA179&dq=secure+web+service+with+adobe+livecycle&source=bl&ots=jm1GIZflOJ&sig=uLfv5Xda4eXXJl5o_7vBViwU-w0&hl=en&sa=X&ei=WLvIT5P4OujW0QWmv7nDAQ&ved=0CI4BEOgBMAk#v=onepage&q=secure%20web%20service%20with%20adobe%20livecycle&f=false

Q2. I've managed to consume the WSDL but can only see the body of the XML request for a particular SOAP action. Where can I add the username/password credentials? I've selected "Requires Message-Level Authentication" during the new connection wizard, but it doesn't prompt me at all for these details.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the user name and password credential from LC adminUi. I believe that there is a user name and password credential setting page under setting/trust store.